# hexo:ERROR Deployer not found: github

Tags: git, github, hexo

**problem:**

```
hexo-blog$ hexo deploy

ERROR Deployer not found: github
```

**then i do this**

```
Hi XXXXXX! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

**and**

```
hexo-blog$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:FantasRu/data-structure-learning.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:FantasRu/data-structure-learning.git (push)
```

**and**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**also I push well**

```
Spider$ git push origin master

Counting objects: 9, done.

Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.

Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 41.43 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.

Total 9 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)

To https://github.com/FantasRu/Spider.git

174fcd0..2fc6d48  master -> master
```

**so whats wrong with my hexo,why cant connect git**

here is deploy settings

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to install [hexo-deployer-git](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-deployer-git) to deploy your generated site with git on a specified branch.

```
npm install hexo-deployer-git --save
```

Be carefull, with your current configuration, you will erase all your source code on `master` branch. I recommend you to deploy on `gh-pages` to be automatically reachable at `https://github.com/username/repository_name`

```
deploy:
    type: git
    repo: <repository url>
    branch: gh-pages
```

Read [hexo - deployment](https://hexo.io/docs/deployment.html#Git) documentation for more information

Answer (score 1):

change type from github to git.